# How to send flutter search to Firebase Analytics event

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to catch only the final search to send in Firebase Analytics event?

```
_searchPressed() {
   final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
   setState(() {
     if (this._searchIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
       this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
       this._appBarTitle = TextField(
         decoration: new InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search),
         ),
         onChanged: (text) {
           text = text.toLowerCase();
           setState(() {
             _itemForDisplay = _item.where((item) {
               var itemTitle = item.code.toLowerCase();
               return itemTitle.contains(text);
             }).toList();
             if (text.length > 6) {
               analytics.logEvent(
                   name: text.replaceAll(' ', ''),
                   parameters: {'term': text.replaceAll(' ', ''), 'vaule': 1}); 
//space not allowed in firebase
             }
           });
         },
       );
     } else {
       this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
       this._appBarTitle = new Text( 'Search bar' );
       analytics.logEvent(
           name: 'search_done',
           parameters: {'term': "close", 'vaule': 1});
       _itemForDisplay = _item;
     }
   });
 }
```

A satisfactory solution is to capture the search when closing search is selected. The search is done simultaneously so there is no information when the search is completed. The only information about the end of the search is when you touch the close icon. Another option would be the longest search text.

Comment: what is closing search here. Can you elaborate what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: When tap Icon.close the search is complete. There is another option: the longest text is the final search term.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.